# S3 x-amz-meta- case sensitivity

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, metadata, case-sensitive

Does amazon S3 assume that the `x-amz-meta-` header is case insensitive so that:

`x-amz-meta-myproperty`
is the same as
`x-amz-meta-MyProperty`

Thanks
David

Answer (score 6):

By standard (HTTP 1.1 RFC, RFC 2616, section 4.2; RFC 822, section 3.4.7) HTTP headers are case insensitive. So Amazon metadata for S3 is then also case insensitive on the keys.

Amazon will flag an error on the metadata header `x-amz-meta-myproperty` followed by `x-amz-meta-MyProperty` as a duplicate. Some S3 clients are not aware of this issue.